# Make the value of the course type a unique color using rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have different courses and I want to add a unique color to the different types of courses. Ex video course, reading course and speaking course.

I understand what my code does. It ask if the type_of_course with "Video" in it is present, and it is, but how do I only display "orange" color for the courses that have "Video" as the course type?

```html
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
     <td class='<%= "type_of_course" if course.type_of_course? %>'>
     <%= course.title %>
<% end %>
```

courses.scss

```
.type_of_course {
    color: orange;
}
```

course.rb

```
def type_of_course?
    type_of_course = Course.find_by(type_of_course: 'Video').present?
end
```

Comment: So the problem is what, exactly?  You don't know what type of course it is?  You don't know how to put the course information into your markup (btw, that is not HTML)?  You don't know how to make an element be orange?

Comment: Why don't make your `type_of_course?` method to return the 'class-name' instead of a `boolean`? (and of course rename it to `get_type_of_course`)

Comment: I want to set colors for each "type_of_course".
Ex. Video Course = color: red, Ex. Reading Course = color: blue, Ex. Speaking Course = color: orange. @cimmanon

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything.  Do we need to show you how to write out a class in CSS for "Reading Course" and "Speaking Course" or do we need to show you how to add a class to your markup?  It would really help a lot if you were posting the compiled HTML, because we have no idea what the contents of those variables are.

Comment: I am sorry if this sounds unclear. 
I know how the CSS works. But I don't know how to implement the each value for each color in the model and html. 
Example: if the value is "video" make the color red, else look what value the string have and print out the set color.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad explanation. I figured it out after a few hours!
Thanks anyway! :)

```css
.level-easy .level { 
 background-color:green; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 
}
.level-medium .level { 
 background-color:orange;
 }
.level-hard .level {
 background-color:red; 

}
```

```html
<tr class='level-<%= course.level %>'>
<td class="text-center level"><%= course.level.upcase %></td>
```